# How to implement: Express (ISO 10303-21) TYPE typename = SELECT in C#

Tags: c#, express, ifc

At the moment I am writing a really basic Early Binding for IFC, that is mapped following the Express-standard described in ISO 10303-21. 
As I've only just started coding two months ago, everything I do is fairly basic still. However, I can already create all the entities and types with all their properties within the given schema. I'm also able to map that to a file, following the ISO. 
There are still a problem I'm coming across:

- in the schema, there are types that are SELECT types, looking like the follwoing:

  ```
  TYPE IfcGridPlacementDirectionSelect = SELECT
  (IfcDirection
  ,IfcVirtualGridIntersection);
  END_TYPE;
  ```

  IfcDirection and IfcVirtualGridIntersection are both entities or types themselves ( I create a class for a type and an entity likewise). 
  My TYPE IfcGridPlacementDirectionSelect - class looks something like this:

  ```
  public class IfcGridPlacementDirectionSelect :IfcBase
  {
     public IfcBase _value { get; set; }
  }
  ```

Is there any way to implement the select structure into csharp so the property-type of _value is either "IfcDirection" or "IfcVirtualGridIntersection" instead of what I'm making it now "IfcBase". So that the SELECT-structure would be represented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is legal. But I think that you shouldn't create classes like that. It breaks IFC's structure.

In my implementation, whenever using `IfcGridPlacementDirectionSelect`, I create 2 functions: one for `IfcDirection` and another for `IfcVirtualGridIntersection`.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented it now by using an Generic Class. This not a very elegant method, but it works. The only problem is, that now the user can select any type. Therfore you gotta rely on the user knowing what he can actually select. For my example that works for now.

```
public class IfcGridPlacementDirectionSelect< T > : IfcBase 
{ 
   public T _value { get; set; } 
}
```